# Undefined reference to MySQL libraries using g++

Tags: c++, mysql, path, linker, g++

I am getting `undefined reference to 'mysql_suchandsuch@#'` messages when trying to link my program with the MySQL libraries supplied with the 5.5 server. When MySQL was installed, I used the default path, which for me on Windows is `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\`. Originally, I had thought that the spaces are causing my grief, but I think I've correctly worked out how to point to the library path without spaces (still with no luck). If there's another probable cause, please let me know.

I have reviewed a series of questions on this site trying to resolve my issue...

- [Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6486447/698590)
- [Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7806773/698590)
- [Question 3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7976014/698590)
- [Question 4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/577006/698590)
- [Question 5](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4797359/698590)
- [Question 6](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8869764/698590)
- [Question 7](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9645844/698590)

Using mingw/g++, I have tried to link using the following options, based on my own research as well as suggestions here:

- -L"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\lib\" -llibmysql.lib
- -L"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\lib\" -lmysqlclient.lib
- -L"C:\Progra~1\MySQL\MySQLS~1.5\lib\" -llibmysql.lib
- -LC:\Progra~1\MySQL\MySQLS~1.5\lib\ -lmysqlclient.lib
- -L"C:\Progra~1\MySQL\MySQLS~1.5\lib\" -lmysql

In all cases, I have put the `-L`/`-l` options at the right-most part of the statement, as I understand this can matter.

I have confirmed the libraries do exist. In the /lib dir, I have libmysql.lib, mysqlclient.lib, and libmysql.dll. I have not tried to link with the .dll, as no tutorial/forum I've reviewed suggested that.

**I am not using MAKEFILES.**

Does anyone have specific experience with g++/MySQL?

Comment: Use `dir /x` this gives the short names for each folder. This way you can get the path to the library without any spaces.

Comment: @Raam That was helpful. Despite using DOS for years, I never learned that trick... Unfortunately, it does not appear that this has resolved my library/linker issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following commands work fine for me using a GCC 4.6.1 from November 2011:

```
g++ my.cpp -I D:\Opt\MySQL5.5\include ^
  D:\Opt\MySQL5.5\lib\libmysql.dll -o myWithDll.exe

g++ my.cpp -I D:\Opt\MySQL5.5\include ^
  -L D:\Opt\MySQL5.5\lib -lmysql -o myWithLib.exe
```

So both linking against the LIB and the DLL do work.

You may get a warning (see Gaffi's comment). This is because the linker does fuzzy linking for you without you having it specified; normally, it would have failed to link. It is being nice, though, and making it work for you, at the same time warning you about things happening without your having requested them. The way to suppress the warning is to make fuzzy linking explicit:

```
g++ -Wl,--enable-stdcall-fixup my.cpp -I D:\Opt\MySQL5.5\include ^
  D:\Opt\MySQL5.5\lib\libmysql.dll -o myWithDll.exe

g++ -Wl,--enable-stdcall-fixup my.cpp -I D:\Opt\MySQL5.5\include ^
  -L D:\Opt\MySQL5.5\lib -lmysql -o myWithLib.exe
```

This is a Cygwin/RedHat/MinGW extension to the linker; [the docs are here](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.22/ld/Options.html):

```
--enable-stdcall-fixup
--disable-stdcall-fixup
```

> If the link[er] finds a symbol that it cannot resolve, it will attempt to
>   do “fuzzy linking” by looking for another defined symbol that differs
>   only in the format of the symbol name (cdecl vs stdcall) and will
>   resolve that symbol by linking to the match. For example, the
>   undefined symbol _foo might be linked to the function _foo@12, or the
>   undefined symbol _bar@16 might be linked to the function _bar. When
>   the linker does this, it prints a warning, since it normally should
>   have failed to link, but sometimes import libraries generated from
>   third-party dlls may need this feature to be usable. If you specify
>   --enable-stdcall-fixup, this feature is fully enabled and warnings
>   are not printed. If you specify --disable-stdcall-fixup, this feature is
>   disabled and such mismatches are considered to be errors. [This option
>   is specific to the i386 PE targeted port of the linker]

Comment: I just tried with this: `"C:\Progra~1\MySQL\MySQLS~1.5\lib\libmysql.dll"` and got the following instead (warnings, but at least it linked!)... `Warning: resolving _mysql_init@4 by linking to _mysql_init
Use --enable-stdcall-fixup to disable these warnings
Use --disable-stdcall-fixup to disable these fixups` Any thoughts on this? Should I use another linker option, or am I good to go?

Answer (score 0):

did you try `-lmysql` as the linker automatically prepends `lib` and appends `.lib`

Comment: I did just try that, no luck. (updating question)